# How to perform on a field by its label using selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How would i perform on an object like Radio button/checkbox/ dropdown by its label using java. I'm going to make a generic code which suppose to work for all page HTML structure. Hence i need to work with the label of the Radio button/checkbox/ dropdown. I can perform on all the object above but that is being the page specific.

I need to make the logic like ...

```
    If label = "Input from user"

then

   driver.find element("that radio/check box associated with the label").click
```

Is there any api that can bring out the value of  tag of the provided  tag xpath on run time????

or any other logic/suggestion will also be highly appreciated to solve the purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway, I drilled down to the exact object by its label and performed my work. Something like this

```
WebElement label = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath"));

WebElement parentOfLabel = label.findElement(By.xpath("parent::*"));

WebElement myObject = parentOfLabel.findElement(By.xpath("*//input[@id='abc']"));

myObject.sendKeys("found");
```

drilldown is the best policy from parent node to child node so that you don't get any wrong node to work with.

Answer (score 0):

```
String label=driver.findElement(By.xpath("")).getText() ;

if(!label.isEmpty()){
//click
}
```

Comment: Thanx for your comment but it wont work for my case as each object has a label, hence your code will click every object. I need to take the label name from user input. And have to match that with current label. If the label math, then it will perform on the particular input element which is sibling with that label tag under same parent tag. So is there any method to get the sibling or near by tag of label tag???

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp you can do this:) try to download xpath checker and firebug it will help you

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.cssselector("[label='Your Label Here']")).Click()
```

Comment: Rechard, this code will click on the label instead of the element. That will not solve the purpose.

Comment: @Rechard, this code will click on the label instead of the element. That will not solve the purpose. Well let me be more clear, Suppose i have one section labeled "Gender". and under this tag I have two Radio button named "Male" and "Female". Hear I'm going to take the user input "Gender" as the label, and selection as "Male". Now my code need to search for the label "Gender" first, and accordingly click on the "Male" if match fount for "Gender" label in the page. This is just an example only. So is there any more suggestion instead of direct selection Male or Female?